# splash screen and icon are not updated when building my app with eas build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, splash-screen

I'm trying to make the .aab and .apk of my application in react native with eas-cli, everything is achieved very well, but despite the fact that I change versions in my app.json, and update the image directories, having the app installed on my phone uses the icons and splash screen that come by default with expo. I would like to know how to make them update, I already verified that my directories were fine

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xooc-numeros",
    "slug": "xooc-numeros",
    "version": "2.2.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/imgs/icon1.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/imgs/splash1.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": [
        "cjs"
      ]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/imgs/adaptative-icon1.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "versionCode": 3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/imgs/adaptative-icon1.png"
    },
    "description": "Contar números en maya"
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
  {
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Run `expo prebuild --clean`. For me, it gave some errors installing pod files. If that's the case, then you need to manually resolve the issues there and run "pod install" in ios/PodFile. Once the pod files are successfully installed, run “expo prebuild”. After this take a build either through `./gradlew assembleRelease` or `eas build` and new build should have the updated app icon as well as splash screen.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue; in my case, the command "eas build" was ignoring the config on app.json. It was ignored because my project had the folder "android" and the build was using the configuration in this folder. After I deleted this directory, solved the problem.
In my case, I don't have any custom configuration in the directory "android". Don't remove this folder before knowing if there is anything that you are using there.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32600774)