# Expo App Icon Not Updating: How to Resolve?

Tags: react-native

I've encountered an issue while trying to change the app icon for my Expo project using the Expo CLI. Despite my efforts, the icon remains unchanged. I've tested this on both iOS and Android within Expo Go, and I've ensured that the image I'm using is 1024x1024 in size. I've even attempted to clear the cache, but the icon stubbornly stays the same.

Interestingly, when I build the app as an APK/AAB and install it, I'm still seeing the default icons, not the custom one I've specified.
I've triple-checked the path to my custom icon image, and it seems correct. However, the app continues to display the default icons.
Here's a screenshot of my app.json [image: app.json]

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Running `expo prebuild --clean` did the job. [Answer from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572455/11578100)

Answer (score 1):

On your app.json file, change the "foreground-image" from "./assets/adaptive-icon" to your icon's relative file path (just like you did on the "icon" key).

I was struggling with this issue till just now.